# Summing over filtered pivot table with pandas / python

Tags: python, pandas, sum, pivot-table

I have a (sliced [by years 1952-1988] and countries [USA and USR]) pivot table of olympic medals with countries (noc), years and corresponding amount of medals:

```
medals_of_usa_urs = df.loc['1952':'1988', ['USA','URS']]
print(medals_of_usa_urs )

noc     USA    URS
year              
1952  130.0  117.0
1956  118.0  169.0
1960  112.0  169.0
1964  150.0  174.0
1968  149.0  188.0
1972  155.0  211.0
1976  155.0  285.0
1980    NaN  442.0
1984  333.0    NaN
1988  193.0  294.0v
```

How can I sum up total medals by country (e.g. for USA a toal of 1495 and URS 2049) in Python?

Comment: do you mean `df.sum()` ?

Comment: yes, how can I sum by the values of 'noc' ('USA', 'USR') to get a total over all years in this table

Comment: medals_of_usa_urs.sum(1) with parameters=1 for column axis (0 if you want row sum)

Comment: `medals_of_usa_urs.sum()` gives what you say, if not can you kindly explain more and post a desired output for more clarity?

Comment: thanks, Clement already answered what I nedded, was not sure about the parameters